# How to prevent Autoclick Spam of upvote/downvote button?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, web-applications, spam-prevention

I have a upvote button, which the user can press and a vote will be registered. On clicking this button again, the vote gets cancelled.

So each press of this button is doing a DataBase Write. If an autoclicker is used on this button continuously, continuous DB calls will happen. I want to prevent this.
What can I do?

PS. I am sending an ajax query to the backend(running Django) when the upvote button is clicked.

Comment: You could use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` on every click, so when the user clicks the previous Timeout is cancelled and only after an amount of time when you haqven't clicked, the ajax call is made

Comment: If someone disables cookies and javascript this could probably be hard to stop :)

Comment: Well if JS are disabled I assume that the click events should not be triggered either. Obviously you can call the server side method, but that's another problem and does not concern an Autoclicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd really want to check this on the server, so it doesn't matter if someone disables javascript.

If you're using PHP one option is to set a time limit between votes.. eg only allow one vote per minute.

So on every vote, store the time of the vote in a session variable, then ignore subsequent votes if it is within the time limit:

```
//on vote
$now=date('U');
if(!isset($_SESSION['lastvote']) || $now - $_SESSION['lastvote']<LIMIT){
    $_SESSION['lastvote']=$now;
    // do database call

}else{
    //throw error
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU. This is the only correct answer. Javascript isn't something that shouldn't be handling this

Comment: Have fun with bots who just call the url repeatedly ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest approach is to disable the buttons while a single operation is running.

To obtain this, assuming you're using a JQuery ajax request to call the "upvote" / "downvote" method you simply have to:

```
$("#upvoteButton").click(function)
{
    $("#upvoteButton").attr("disabled");
    $.ajax({
      url: 'url/upvote.extension',
      success: function(data) {
        $("#upvoteButton").removeAttr("disabled");
      }
    });
}
```

This way a single request is send & resolved per single tab / window.

Comment: Thanks! One Doubt. Will this allow another request to be sent, once the response to the previous request has been completed?

Comment: @user1912328 That's exactly what should happen. Although there should probably be an `error` option included, where the same code inside of `success` is done

Answer (score 0):

If you trust that your users accept cookies, you could store the click together with the object id and a timestamp in the session, and test whether the user clicked the vote button during the last n seconds.

You also could disable the vote button on the web page with javascript, and enable it again after n seconds to revoke the vote.

Both suggestions are dependent on users who use a javascript enabled or cookie enabled browser.

If you have to take bots into consideration who just send the url repeatetly to the server, you need to take a different approach - e.g. check whether the current ip address has called the url in the last n seconds and raise a 403 Forbidden http error or something.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `setTimeout` you can try something like this:

```
var toggleVote = (function () {
  var voted = false,timeout;
  return function () {
     if( timeout )
       clearTimeout(timeout)

     voted = !voted

      timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Ajax call - vote : " + voted)
      },400)
    }
  })()

document.getElementById("vote").addEventListener("click",toggleVote)
```

Heres an example on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/otexos/1/edit)

Try mashing the "Click me" div

Answer (score 0):

Easy way:

```
<button id="upvote" onclick="upvote(this)">Up</button>

<script>
   var upvote = function(x){
      $(x).removeAttr('onclick'); //if you click this button again, it will do nothing

      //call ajax to do something here...
      //...............
      //after finishing, add attribute onclick to the button
      $(x).attr('onclick', 'upvote(this)')
   };
</script>
```